# Optimizing the registerfile code in systemverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am implementing a 32bit RegFile(containing 32 registers). Now, for the combinational part, I am planning to use the switch case to out the read value of the 32registers based on the input register number. This is resulting in a switch case with 32cases and a default case. Is there any other way to optimize the code? Constraint is that my output needs to be a register and hence I am unable to use the following statement(containing assign):

```
assign rdDataA = rdAddrA == 0 ? reg0
```

Code:

```
module RegFile(input [4:0] src_rd_1,
       input [4:0] src_rd_2,
       input [4:0] des_wr_1,
       input [31:0] data,
       input clk,
       input reset,
       input wr_en,
       output reg rd_val_1,
       output reg rd_val_2
            );

reg [31:0] register[31:0];

always_comb begin
case(src_rd_1)
5'd0:begin
rd_val_1=register[0];
end
5'd1:begin
rd_val_1=register[1];
end
5'd2:begin
rd_val_1=register[2];
end
5'd3:begin
rd_val_1=register[3];
end
5'd4:begin
rd_val_1=register[4];
//and so on...
end
```

Update:
I found out a way to optimize the code. I hope this would work...Any other suggestions are welcome

```
if(src_rd_1>=0)
begin 
    if(src_rd_1==0)
    begin 
    rd_val_1=32'd0;
    end
else
    begin
    rd_val_1=register[src_rd_1];
    end
end
```

Any advise will helpful. TIA

Comment: Why does the output need to be a register?

Comment: @Greg The spec sheet needs the output to be a register. I am also trying to understand the preference of the register over a wire...

Answer (score 0):

The following is allowed by simulation tools:

```
always_comb begin
  rd_val_1 = register[src_rd_1];
end
```

You'll have to try it out and see if your synthesis tool supports this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `reg` doesn't mean it will synthesize to a register. To synthesize to a register a `reg` (or for SystemVerilog`preferably`logic`) should be assigned in a sequential always block.

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
  rd_val_1 <= register[src_rd_1];
end
```

Flopping the output makes it a clean, glitch-free output and doesn't add to the combinational propagation delay to any receiving modules.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? Why do we need to flop the output?